# Error installing gems - not sure why

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I keep getting errors like the following when I try to gem intall :

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'ruby-gmail' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

For the life of me, I don't know why this is happening. I've had no problems previously.

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you recently upgrade Ruby? Do you have an up-to-date SSL library on your system?

Comment: I just installed Mavericks yesterday. Not sure about the SSL library. Where can I check that?

Comment: Open a terminal window and type `openssl version` to find out what the system OpenSSL version is in Mavericks. Are you using the Ruby that came with Xcode, or did you install your own? If the latter, newer versions of Ruby want an SSL library > 1.something.

Comment: "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013"

Comment: I'm using RVM: /Users/evanzamir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

Comment: I just checked on another machine where I'm testing Mavericks, and it's OpenSSL 0.9.8y. If you built Ruby from source, it probably gave you a warning about the SSL version.

Comment: I don't use RVM, so I can't help you with that, but I'd bet good money that the Ruby 2 installation is unhappy with the OpenSSL version number from Mavericks. I would expect the RVM maintainer to fix that pretty soon, but in the meantime anything in Ruby that requires SSL will barf.